# Javascript seems to be ignoring my functions

Tags: javascript, html

Im having a small problem with my code and i was wondering if someone could explain what i am doeing wrong.

The first textbox should get focus when the page is loaded but that doesnt seem to work either.

The code underneath should jump from 1 textbox to another when the the first textbox reaches a specific number of characters.

The second textbox should submit the form after the textbox reaches a specific number of characters.

So i know the functions `check() and submit()` dont work,
But i cannot figure out what the problem is.

Can someone help me?

```
<head>
    <!-- Include the needed files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script language="javascript">

        function check() {
            var inhoud = document.formsubmit.locatienummer.value.length + 1;
            if (inhoud <= 10)
            { document.formsubmit.locatienummer.focus() }
            else
            { document.formsubmit.bonnummer.focus() }
        }

        <!-- This code makes the form submit -->
        function submit() {
            var inhoud2 = document.bonnummer.value.length + 1;
            if (inhoud2 <= 10)
            { document.formsubmit.bonnummer.focus() }
            else
            { document.formsubmit.submit() }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="document.formsubmit.locatienummer.focus()">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Locatiescanner</legend>
            <br />
            <form name="formsubmit" method="POST">
                Locatienummer:
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="locatienummer" onkeyup="check()"><br />
                Bonnummer:
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="bonnummer" onkeyup="submit()"><br />
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `onkeyup` (lowercase)

Comment: @atmd HTML (unlike XHTML) is case-insensitive, though conventionally people tend to stick to lowercase.  `onKeyUp` should be fine though.

Comment: Should it reallyt matter if its lower or uppercase? I tried but it doesnt work. Still thanks for the comment

Comment: The doctype isn't included so was just a suggestion

Comment: you made a typo here :  <form name"formsubmit" method="POST"> it can be a problem it should be `name="formsubmit"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the equals sign

```
<form name"formsubmit" method="POST">
```

/

```
<form name="formsubmit" method="POST">
```

Comment: REAAAALY, am i that stupid? Thanks for spotting such a dumb mistake.

Comment: it's ok, we all do that kind of things and we know it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid try this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Locatiescanner</legend><br/>
        <form name="formsubmit" method="POST">
            Locatienummer: <br/>
            <input type="text" name="locatienummer" onKeyUp="check()"/><br/>
            Bonnummer: <br/>
            <input type="text" name="bonnummer" onKeyUp="submit()"/><br/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

You forgot the `=` sign from `<form name"formsubmit" method="POST">`
and you didn't end the input element